# Storing a string as char[] with placement new and get it back

Tags: c++, string, pointer-arithmetic, placement-new

I want to write a Class which holds information about a string in Memory and which can give it back to me. So i started with a Union which holds the size of a string. (why union doesn't matter here but it need to be union for other types lateron) The constructor get a string passed and should put the string as c_str at the end of the Objekt which i place with placement new.
The class looks like this:

```
class PrimitivTyp
{
public:
    explicit PrimitivTyp(const std::string &s);
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> getString() const;
private:
    union
    {
        long long m_long; //use long long for string size
        double m_double;
    } m_data;
    ptrdiff_t m_next;
};
```

And the impl of the Ctor and the get function looks like this which doesnt work properly i guess.

```
PrimitivTyp::PrimitivTyp(const std::string& s)
{
    m_data.m_long = s.size();
    m_next = reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>(nullptr);
    //calc the start ptr
    auto start = reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t*>(this + sizeof(PrimitivTyp));
    memcpy(start, s.c_str(), s.size()); //cpy the string
}

std::shared_ptr<std::string> PrimitivTyp::getString() const
{
    auto string = std::make_shared<std::string>();
    //get the char array
    auto start = reinterpret_cast<ptrdiff_t>(this + sizeof(PrimitivTyp)); //get the start point
    auto size = m_data.m_long; //get the size
    string->append(start, size);//appand it
    return string;//return the shared_ptr as copy
}
```

The Usage should be something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //checking type
    char buffer[100];
    PrimitivTyp* typ = new(&buffer[0]) PrimitivTyp("Testing a Type");
    LOG_INFO << *typ->getString();
}
```

This crashes and i don't find the misstake with the Debugger. I think it is something with the position calculation of `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this + sizeof(PrimitivTyp)` is not what you think, you want `this + 1` or `reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(this) + sizeof(PrimitivTyp)`.

Pointer arithmetic in C and C++ takes into account the type of the pointer.

so with `T* t;`, `(t + 1)` is `&t[1]` (assuming non overload of `operator &`) or `reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t>(t) + sizeof(T))`.

Comment: But doesnt this point to the first element in memory? (so first member)

Comment: Thanks alot. I guess i need to change it to more simple thing like so: ` auto start = this + 1;
 memcpy(start, s.c_str(), s.size()); //cpy the string` and if i retrive itthe same just cast the start to (char*). Didn't know that it takes the type into account as you said. Thanks for the clarifiation